# iPad's "define" feature on Windows

Tags: windows, dictionary

I've bought iPad yesterday,  and one of the things that I liked the most is ability to select word in any application, tap "define" and dictionary popup will show.

I wonder if there is application out there that provides similar feature on Windows (mark and hot-key, for example)?

Comment: Windows 7 does not have a built in dictionary this was added to Windows 8 to a certain degree.  This would require third-party on software Windows 7 and said features would be specific to the program selected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use a feature something like define in a web browser (chrome) you can get a add on. Here is one I use: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/google-dictionary-by-goog/mgijmajocgfcbeboacabfgobmjgjcoja?hl=en